# How to skip evaluating remaining part of arithmetic expression after 0 * ... in Java

Tags: java, arithmetic-expressions

In logic expressions remaining part would be skipped if it is unnecessary

```
boolean b = false && checkSomething( something)
//checkSomething() doesn't get called
```

What is a good way to achieve the same with arithmetic expressions ?

```
int i = 0 * calculateSomethig ( something )
```

It is possible to add ifs before * . But is there a more elegant way to solve this problem? Without of adding much stuff into expression, so that expression itself would look as close to original as possible

Why i do not want to use ifs?
from

```
return calculateA() * calculateB()
```

it'll become bulky and unclear

```
int result
int a = calculateA();
if (a!=0) {
    result = a*calculateB()
}else{
    result = 0
}
return result
```

- 8 lines of code instead of 1,
- those expressions might be more complex than a*b
- those expressions represent business logic so i want to    keep them
  clear and easily readable
- there might be whole bunch of them

Why do i bother with this at all?
Because calculation methods might be expensive

- uses values form other places, where searches and sorts are happening
- lots of those expressions can be executed at once ( after user event and user should see result "instantly"
- P( *0 in expression ) >0.5

Comment: No. If it's a possibility that you're doing zero multiplication and you don't want to execute `calculateSomething`, use an `if`. As far as "problems" go, this isn't a very big one.

Comment: It almost sounds as if you're asking if Java has operator overloading similar to C++, but *fortunately* it does not.

Comment: Don't worry about this, until you can prove for definite that not skipping the rest of the calculation is a significant performance issue. Leave it to the JIT to determine where applying such a transformation would actually be of benefit.

Comment: @Andy Turner calculateSomething () is potentially expensive method because it may use numbers that are produced by other methods from complex datatypes with searches etc. so if possible it's better to avoid this.

Comment: @Kayaman
ill use ifs if i'll be unable to find a better solution, but i do not like it because  instead of 
return calculateOneThing () * calculateAnotherThing ()
cod would get much more messier
like 
int oneThing = calculateOneThing (); 
if (oneThing != 0) 
return oneThing * calculateAnotherThing();
... much more messier. and i want those expressions to stay clear and simple, because they represent business logic. better to separate them form ifs and stuff

Comment: further more - expression in actual program might be more complex that a*b.

Comment: First of all, there are no short-circuit operators in Java apart from the ones you already know. So the only way to do it is to write your own equivalents.

Comment: Use the ternary operator. I'm pretty sure you can reduce that 8 lines. :)

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz Or you can write it all in a single line. But neither that, nor the ternary operator simplifies the problem.

Comment: @biziclop Since the problem is "how could I write this more elegantly", yes it does.

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz No, because you have to still keep a separate variable in order to avoid evaluating the same thing twice, i.e. `a() == 0 ? 0 : a() * b()` is not really useful here, you have to do `int res = a(); res = res == 0 ? 0 : res * b();`, which is not a single expression any more.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` and `||` are called short-circuit operators because they don't evaluate if the JVM will find the value of the whole expression without evaluating the whole expression. For example, the JVM does not have to evaluate the second part of the following expression to tell it evaluates to `true`:

```
6 == (2 + 4) || 8 == 9
```

The JVM does not have to evaluate all of the following expression either to tell it evaluates to `false`:

```
9 == 8 && 7 == 7
```

The multiplication operator (*) is not a short-circuit operator. And so, it does not behave that way. You can do this as you mentioned using `if` statements. There is no predefined way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a structure that uses lambdas to evaluate its arguments lazily:

```
class LazyMul implements IntSupplier {
    private final IntSupplier [] args;

    private LazyMul(IntSupplier[] args) {
        //argument checking omitted for brevity :)
        this.args = args;
    }

    public static LazyMul of(IntSupplier ... args) {
        return new LazyMul(args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        int res = 1;
        for (IntSupplier arg: args) {
            res *= arg.getAsInt();
            if (res == 0)
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Of course this is even longer but using it is as simple as `LazyMul.of(this::calculateA, this::calculateB)`, so if you use it several times, it's better than having an `if` every time around.

Unfortunately with complicated (particularly nested) expressions readability suffers, but these are the limitations of Java as a language.